# Adding characters to str_replace in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a php file with thread ($tid) and post ($pid) ids defined and I'm looking to use str_replace to combine them and create my desired output (below) with **&p=** added:

Desired output:

```
$tid&amp;p=$pid
```

The closest I've got is doing this:

```
$tid=$t1;
$pid=$p1;
$tid=str_replace("$tid","$tid"."$pid",$tid);
```

The result is:

```
$tid$pid
```

I may need to use a function (not sure which if so?) in the str_replace to support the **&p=** being added, as trying to add it in the quotes directly doesn't seem to work resulting only in database errors.

**Edit #1:** I tried doing the following based on the comments thus far:

```
$tid="";
$tid.="$t1";
$tid.="$p1"; 
$tid=$tid;
```

That results in the same as my previous example above:

```
$tid$pid
```

As soon as I add another with the **&p=** I get a database error:

```
$tid.="&amp;p=";
```

So my question now is how to add the **&p=** to my **Edit #1** example above correctly?

Comment: Don't understand why not to do simple concat without str_replace?

Comment: just use like this: $tid . '&amp;p' . $pid

Comment: I edited the post above with my latest attempt. Thanks!

Comment: You get a what? Database error? That makes no sense at all. What does the error say?

Comment: @tkausl It tells me to check my syntax, because what it's doing when I add the &amp;p= into the $tid from the Edit #1 example is adding that &amp;p= to the SELECT FROM / WHERE query when it shouldn't be (should only be shown on the output to link the $tid and $pid together).

Comment: I don't get it. Sorry, but i don't get what you're trying to accomplish and i don't get what your problem with the Database is. Can you post a bit more code and tell __exactly__ what should happen? Because `$whatever = $tid . '&amp;p=' . $pid;` should do the job, if it doesn't, your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Using that code from your reply (replacing $whatever with my own) the MySQL Error is Unknown column 't1&amp;p=p1' in 'where clause' so I guess I need to sort another way to add the &amp;p= outside of the $whatever.. thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm attempting to understand the question a little bit.  You have a couple options that are alluded to in the comments above.  You could, for instance (where '1', '2', and '3' are replaced by the desired values):

```
<?php
$tid=1;
$pid=2;
$amp=3;
$tid=str_replace("$tid","$tid".'$amp;p='."$pid",$tid);

echo $tid;
?>
```

Here you can just explicitly state in the 'replace' argument of str_replace that the missing string should be part of the replacement string.

or you could also simply use the a concatenation operator to generate the string you desire which is probably simpler given what (little) I know of the surrounding code/use-case:

```
<?php
$tid=1;
$pid=2;
$amp=3;

echo "$tid".'$amp;p='."$pid";
?>
```

The reason I'd recommend the latter, is due to the fact that it's less resource intensive to actually produce the desired result which appears to just be a string.  str_replace() searches the "haystack" or subject string using the search string and then must replace each of the found instances with the replace string.